# Is it possible to run/ install sharepoint on MySQL

Tags: installation, database, sql

as in the title you can read, I wonder if it is possible to install and run SharePoint (does not matter what version) on an other SQL-Platform than Microsoft?

For example: MySQL, Oracle SQL, etc. Also, does it always have to be the database with SQL? Can I install and run SharePoint on other database-technologies, too?

If it is possible, I would be really grateful if you could also explain how to config and install SharePoint for example on MySQL?

If it is not possible, please say why.

**Also it does not matter, if the possibility is official or a hack**

Comment: I believe it may actually be possible. you would still need a Microsoft SQL Server but you would instead call stored procedures which are wrappers for Linked Server calls to Stored Procedure with the code your running. though i haven't tested it out, just a theory

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible. You need Microsoft SQL Server. More info in [Hardware and software requirements for SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx).
Technet.

Comment: This is my opinion. Working more than 10 years ago with SharePoint. But I also work with WordPress, PHP and mySQL. I like both platforms. But under no point of view I would recommend to a client attempting to run SharePoint with mySQL. I'm sure that sooner or later fail and I would have gotten into a problem. This is my recommendation.

Comment: SharePoint is definitiely bound to MS SQL Server, as it uses many built-in and exclusive features of SQL Server. There's no way to "trick" it...

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to run it using MySQL server. You can use express edition for simple tasks but if your databases go more than 4GB I suggest you use many web apps instead (divide the work). For big companies it will be impossible to use SQL express edition so you would have to buy SQL Server. MySQL is not an available solution.

Comment: The limit for the latest versions of SQL Express is now 10GB. Also, you don't have to use multiple Web apps to split your data accross different DBs in order to avoid this 10GB limitation: you may simply create different site collections stored in different DBs, but all hosted in the same Web app.